# Почему модальное окно прижимает или фиксирует к верху

Tags: html, css, bootstrap4

У меня на сайте модальные окна. А так же в них есть по всплывающему окну с формой . Но при закрытии формы.. Основное модальное окно прижимается к верху (фиксируеться) И ездииет вместе с прокрыткой прижатая к верху ..
Пожайлуста помогите решить 
Вот сайт http://crafturaltay.ru/

Comment: Вам лучше issue в гитхабе бутстрапа создать. Это скорее недоработка самого фреймворка. Ну или во время открытия окна с формой закрывать остальные.

Comment: При закрытие модального окна с формой у вас с body удаляется класс "modal-open". Как вариант можете воспользоваться не стандартным методом закрытия модального окна, а написать свой код, который не будет задевать body